# Get HTTP request data from a webview plugin from a flutter or ionic app

Tags: flutter, http, ionic-framework, webview, flutter-inappwebview

Does anybody know how or if it's possible to listen to HTTP requests that happen inside a Webview plugin hosted on either a Flutter or Ionic app? I need to see the payload of a post request that is sent from within the Webview and communicate that back to the app (without modifying the source HTML) so the app can register the user.

In plain english - get payload data from POST request within Webview that is inside an Ionic / flutter application.

Or even to catch the data from the webview before its sent in the request also works, each example i have seen involves modifying the source html.

yes i know it sounds sketch af and probably is a huge security vulnarbility

Thank you for reading my weird question any help greatly appreciated